# Comprobar edad con DateTime en Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Estoy haciendo un formulario en el que el usuario selecciona su fecha de nacimiento; estoy intentando que la fecha máxima que se pueda seleccionar sea la fecha actual menos 18 (para que los menores de edad no puedan seleccionar su fecha) y no lo consigo, todo el rato me da error:

> '!initialDate.isAfter(lastDate)'

Aunque ponga las dos fechas como la fecha actual -18.

Este es el código que sí funciona pero la fecha máxima es la actual:

```dart
_seleccionarDia(BuildContext context) async {
  DateTime newSelectedDate = await showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      initialDate: DateTime(int.parse(formatter.format(now))),
      firstDate: DateTime(1900),
      lastDate: DateTime(int.parse(formatter.format(now))),
      builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
        return Theme(
          data: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
            colorScheme: ColorScheme.dark(
              primary: Colores().verdeOscuro,
              onPrimary: Colors.white,
              surface: Colores().verdeClaro,
              onSurface: Colors.green,
            ),
            dialogBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
          ),
          child: child,
        );
      });
  if (newSelectedDate != null) {
    _selectedDate = newSelectedDate;
    _contraladorCumple
      ..text = DateFormat.yMMMd().format(_selectedDate)
      ..selection = TextSelection.fromPosition(TextPosition(
          offset: _contraladorCumple.text.length,
          affinity: TextAffinity.upstream));
  }
}
```

### SOLUCIONADO:

Poniendo `DateTime(int.parse(formatterAno.format(now))-18)` como *intialDay* y *lastDate* funciona.

```
var now                     =  new DateTime.now();
  var formatterAno            =  new DateFormat("y");

 _seleccionarDia                 (BuildContext context) async {
    DateTime newSelectedDate = await showDatePicker(
        context: context,
        initialDate: DateTime(int.parse(formatterAno.format(now))-18),
        firstDate: DateTime(1900),
        lastDate: DateTime(int.parse(formatterAno.format(now))-18),
        builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
          return Theme(
            data: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
              colorScheme: ColorScheme.dark(
                primary: Colores().verdeOscuro,
                onPrimary: Colors.white,
                surface: Colores().verdeClaro,
                onSurface: Colors.green,
              ),
              dialogBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
            ),
            child: child,
          );
        }
    );
    if (newSelectedDate != null) {
      _selectedDate = newSelectedDate;
      _contraladorCumple
        ..text = df.format(_selectedDate)
        ..selection = TextSelection.fromPosition(TextPosition(
            offset: _contraladorCumple.text.length,
            affinity: TextAffinity.upstream));
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya lo arreglé, el código queda así:

```
  var now                     =  new DateTime.now();
  var formatterAno            =  new DateFormat("y");

 _seleccionarDia                 (BuildContext context) async {
    DateTime newSelectedDate = await showDatePicker(
        context: context,
        initialDate: DateTime(int.parse(formatterAno.format(now))-18),
        firstDate: DateTime(1900),
        lastDate: DateTime(int.parse(formatterAno.format(now))-18),
        builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
          return Theme(
            data: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
              colorScheme: ColorScheme.dark(
                primary: Colores().verdeOscuro,
                onPrimary: Colors.white,
                surface: Colores().verdeClaro,
                onSurface: Colors.green,
              ),
              dialogBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
            ),
            child: child,
          );
        }
    );
    if (newSelectedDate != null) {
      _selectedDate = newSelectedDate;
      _contraladorCumple
        ..text = df.format(_selectedDate)
        ..selection = TextSelection.fromPosition(TextPosition(
            offset: _contraladorCumple.text.length,
            affinity: TextAffinity.upstream));
    }
  }
```

Comment: Puedes aceptar tu propia respuesta sin problemas. Lo único es que hay que esperar 48h

Answer (score 0):

Bien, el problema que tienes es que la "lastDate" siempre debe ser mayor a la "initialDate", es una propiedad del datepicker. Lo que te puedo recomendar es que hagas una validación después de que el usuario seleccione la fecha y verifiques si tiene mas de 18 años o no.

Comment: Sí, eso lo entiendo, lo que no comprendo es por qué si pongo en initialDate y lastDate "now" sí funciona y si le resto a ambas 18 no. Intenté también verificar la fecha a posterior pero no fui capaz

Comment: Puedes subir un ejemplo de como estas restando el (-18) para ver cual puede ser el error.